# French resources for (Geometric) Group Theory

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I am looking for ways to improve my mathematical French while learning more material about either finite group theory or geometric group theory. In particular, I would love to find a French equivalent to Rotman's group theory book, if possible. As far as geometric group theory goes, I am open to about anything, but I love Cayley graphs and hyperbolic groups. I apologize if this request is too vague, but do any of you have suggestions for French texts in these areas? In terms of mathematical background, I would consider myself a beginner with a decent foundation in these subjects. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Serre's book on representation theory or the one on trees. 

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't come across: 
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1086648

Comment: Also: http://www.amazon.com/Geometrie-theorie-groupes-hyperboliques-Mathematics/dp/3540529772


Comment: @Agol: Some years ago I had to give a course in French to the local group theorists so that they could read the book by Ghys and de la Harpe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest the survey articles of [Séminaire Bourbaki](http://numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?j=SB), such as

Ghys, Étienne
Groupes aléatoires (d'après Misha Gromov,…). 
Astérisque No. 294 (2004), viii, 173–204.

Ghys, Étienne 
Les groupes hyperboliques. Séminaire Bourbaki, 32 (1989-1990), Exposé No. 722, [36 p.](http://numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SB_1989-1990__32__203_0)

Tits, Jacques 
Groupes à croissance polynomiale. Séminaire Bourbaki, 23 (1980-1981), Exposé No. 572, [13 p.](http://numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SB_1980-1981__23__176_0)

At a more elementary level, there are short articles on various topics in the [*Gazette des Mathématiciens*](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Gazette/), such as

*Topologie, théorie des groupes et problèmes de décision* by Pierre de la Harpe in [volume 125](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Gazette/2010/125/).

At an even more elementary level, there are many highly readable and visually appealing online
articles in the [Images des Mathématiques](http://images.math.cnrs.fr/)

such as [this one](http://images.math.cnrs.fr/Un-concept-mathematique-trois.html):

*Un concept mathématique, trois notions : Les groupes au XIXe siècle chez Galois, Cayley, Dedekind*, by Caroline Ehrhardt.

Happy reading !